# How do I let a JSplitPane move smooth?

Tags: java, swing, jsplitpane

I have a simple Java Swing GUI with a `JSplitPane` to divide two JPanels. Now I wonder how I let it move smooth, so you can see it moving when resizing the window. The standard setting is very ugly, because the `JSplitPane` only moves if you release it.
I spend a lot of time searching for something like that.

Is there any function in the Class `JSplitPane` to move it smooth?

Comment: I too spent a long time faffing with java swing recently. I would highly recommend JavaFX with SceneBuilder 

Comment: Yeah `Swing` seems pretty complicated sometimes. I will inform me about JavaFX and SceneBuilder. Thanks for the hint

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you are looking for [`JSplitPane#setContinuousLayout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JSplitPane.html#setContinuousLayout(boolean))

> Sets the value of the continuousLayout property, which must be true for the child components to be continuously redisplayed and laid out during user intervention. The default value of this property is look and feel dependent. Some look and feels might not support continuous layout; they will ignore this property.